# How to create Newsletter in drupal?

Tags: emails

I want to create a newsletter in drupal. What i want is the ability to subscribe the users that are not registered to the site. I can use the third party or any contrib modules available . Any help ..?

Comment: check this https://www.drupal.org/node/645108

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) module.

```
Simplenews publishes and sends newsletters to lists of subscribers. Both anonymous and 
authenticated users can opt-in to different mailing lists. HTML email can be sent by 
adding Mime Mail module.
```